# How to construct customized ssh connection from ansible playbook

Tags: ssh, parameters, ansible, arguments, connection

The below ssh connection by ansible fails to connect to remote hosts

```
ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/app/ssh_keys/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ControlPath=/home/ansibleuser/.ansible/cp/6abdc12511 -tt 10.9.88.205 'id mwweb || id webadm || ls -ld /web'
```

whereas when i remove the below two arguments from ssh my connection succeeds

```
1. -tt 
2.  -o ControlPath=/home/ansibleuser/.ansible/cp/6abdc12511
```

Working ssh command that is want ansible to construct.

```
ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/app/ssh_keys/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 10.9.88.205 'id mwweb || id webadm || ls -ld /web'
```

This requirement (customized ssh command) is for a specific playbook for specific target hosts that is supplied as arguments to my ansible playbook below. I dont wish to modify the existing ssh configuration at OS:

```
- name: Play 2- Configure Source nodes
  hosts: all
  user: root
  ignore_errors: yes
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

   - name: Get HTTPD userid on server
     raw: id mwweb || id webadm || ls -ld /web

   - name: Get OHS userid on server
     raw: id mwweb
```

The above playbook runs using this command:

```
ansible-playbook -i 10.9.88.205, -f 5 testpython.yml -vvvv
```

I'm using jenkin's ansible plugin to trigger the above playbook.

Can you please provide solution for the below:

1. can i disable `-tt` and `ControlPath` by modifying playbook code? This is my first preference. Please suggest?
2. If modifying the playbook wont help then how can i disable both ssh args using ansible parameters?

I was able to disable -tt using below:

```
ansible-playbook -i 10.9.88.205, -f 5 testpython.yml -e ansible_ssh_use_tty=no -vvvv
```

But, there is no way to could find to disable `ControlPath` despite passing `-e control_path=""`

Reference: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/ssh.html

Can you please suggest ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't customize the Ansible configuration by adding an ansible conf file.

> Changes can be made and used in a configuration file which will be processed in the following order:

- ANSIBLE_CONFIG (an environment variable)
- ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
- .ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
- /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

On Ansible documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/intro_configuration.html#environmental-configuration

> On some systems with very long hostnames or very long path names (caused by long user names or deeply nested home directories) this can exceed the character limit on file socket names (108 characters for most platforms). In that case, you may wish to shorten the string to something like the below:
> ***control_path = %(directory)s/%%h-%%r***

You can also set your ssh_args one that file:

```
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s
```

your ssh config section will look like that with the custom ssh args:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s
```

Comment: im not looking for a solution about modifying the global ssh configuration file. I want the solution of disabling both ssh arguments `-tt` and `-o ControlPath`  in the playbook `testpython.yml` or in `ansible-playbook` command-line.

Comment: hello, if you specify your custom ssh_args, it will disabled the default ssh args. You can interact with the ssh args by using ansible conf file. ( either local for one project) or globally for all ansible project) depends on the conf file you use

Comment: There is no option for `ssh_args` for passing it in ansible-playbook command-line like how we have for `tty`  i.e `-e ansible_ssh_use_tty=no`. Requesting you to provide a solution by either modifying my `testpython.yml` or share the exact `-e <argument>` to `ansible-playbook` @idriss Eliguene

Comment: BASED ON YOUR COMMAND LINE TRY THIS: ```ansible-playbook your_playbook.yml --ssh-common-args="-o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/app/ssh_keys/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"```. I use the ```--ssh-common-arg``` flags to pass the exactly ssh args that you want.

Comment: ```ansible-playbook your_playbook.yml --ssh-common-args="-o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile=\"/app/ssh_keys/id_rsa\"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User=\"root\"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"```